# Calculating a students mass when on a balanced plank

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I have the question " A plank is set up and the balanced is zeroed. When the student lies on the plank the reading on the balance is 600N. The balance is 1.75m from the students's feet and the centre of gravity of the student is 1.25 m from their feet. Calculate what is the students mass ? "

[image]

I know that W = mg, where W is the weight, m is the mass and g is the value of gravity.

Therefore m = W/g = 600N / 9.81 N

Which equals m = 61.16 N.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Something's wrong with your units. Weight is measured in Newtons, but the units for the gravitational constant $g$ aren't Newtons, nor are they the units of mass.

Comment: Also, how are you taking into account that they're lying on a plank, and not standing directly on the scale?

Comment: Yes thanks :) it should be ms^-2 right ? So the final answer should be 61.16 kg ?

Comment: Because it shows it in the picture ?

Comment: That's the correct way to fix the units, yes. Taking the plank into account is what the answer below by Ross Millikan tells you how to do. The calculation you've shown here is how you would find the mass *if* the student were simply standing directly on the scale, with no questions of torque.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used the length of the plank and the location of the student's cg.  You need to balance the torques around the foot end of the plank.

Comment: I know that the length of the plank is 1.75 m from the students feet and 1.25 m from the students feet to the centre of gravity. So the length from the centre of gravity to the students head is 0.5 m . So is it 0.5 x 600 = 300 ? I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: When the force is perpendicular to the radius, torque is force time the distance from center.